# Use filter on ng-options to change the value displayed

Tags: angularjs, filter, ng-options

I have an array of prices (`0`, `0.99`, `1.99`... etc) that I want to display in `<select>`.

I want to use Angular's `ng-options` like this

```
<select ng-model="create_price" ng-options="obj for obj in prices"/>
```

As it is displayed above it will generate a selection of `0`, `0.99`, `1.99`...

But I want to use a filter in the code such that every time the word *'prices'* is presented (or something like that), the code will run a function to change the float numbers to strings and present (`free`, `0.99$`, `1.99$`... etc).

I there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 114, accepted):

There's a better way:

```
app.filter('price', function() {
  return function(num) {
    return num === 0 ? 'free' : num + '$';
  };
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
<select ng-model="create_price" ng-options="obj as (obj | price) for obj in prices">
</select>
```

This way, the filter is useful for single values, rather than operating only on arrays. If you have objects and corresponding formatting filters, this is quite useful.

Filters can also be used directly in code, if you need them:

```
var formattedPrice = $filter('price')(num);
```

Comment: Thanks!
Except for the syntax error you added - no need for the fourth line round bracket.
Beside that the answer works great!

Comment: For clarity, you could add parentheses to the expression: `obj as (obj | price) for obj in prices`. The syntax is slightly less intimidating.

Comment: If any else arrived here in search of a standard currency filter for use with `ng-options` then this may be useful: `option as (option | currency:'$':0) for option in pricesArr`

Answer (score 7):

You want to create the custom filter such as:

```
app.filter('price', function() {
  return function(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(num){
      return num === 0 ? 'free' : num + '$';
    });
  };
});
```

use it like:

```
<select ng-model="create_price" ng-options="obj for obj in prices | price">
  {{ obj }}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pardon the pseudo code

```
data-ng-options="( obj.property | myFilter ) for obj in objects"

app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(displayValue) {
    return (should update displayValue) ? 'newDisplayValue' : displayValue;
});
```

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good. In its current state your answer might not be of much use to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Comment: Thanks ! This was what  I was looking for.. ```( obj.property | myFilter ) for obj in objects```, but yea, explanation is key