# AngularJS - ngOptions conditional

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select box like this basically it goes through an array of departments to see which items is a viable parent department

```
<select class="editSelectBox" ng-model="dept.parentDepartment" 
ng-options="dept as dept.name for dept in depts track by dept.id" 
ng-change="dept.parentDepartment" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```

But, a dept can't have a parent that's itself. Is there anyway to not display an option that allows it set itself as a parent? Since it is going through an array of all departments, the option will be there unless given a conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put a filter in your `ng-options`. This filter should take your array of departments and remove the department you don't want. You will therefore need to pass that department, or at least its index, to your filter function

```
ng-options=".. as ... for .. in depts | filterFunction:dept"
```

See [Use filter on ng-options to change the value displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644402/angular-use-filter-on-ng-options-to-change-the-value-displayed)

Comment: I can't seem to pass in the department as passing it into the filterFunction is always referencing to itself...

Comment: You want to filter the LIST of departments and pass ONE department as an argument to the filter.

Comment: In this case, the 'dept' in your filter is not the same as the 'dept' in your ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The problem I was having was by returning a list of department, I am still referencing the the whole scope's department list. What I did was create a deep copy of departments and returning the filtered departments! Your advice helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a filtered version of the `depts` array updated in the callback of a watcher of `dept.parentDepartment`.

Why not an angular filter ? because it is evaluated at each digest loop.