# How to apply date filter to ng-select ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I've a nested repeat list as follows and I'm wondering how to apply 06-27-15 (mm-dd-yy) date format to values.

```
<select ng-model="data.dayId" ng-value="day.id" ng-options="day.id as day.date group by day.name for day in days" required>

</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular - Use filter on ng-options to change the value displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644402/angular-use-filter-on-ng-options-to-change-the-value-displayed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ng-options="day.id as (day.date | date:'mm-dd-yy') group by day.name for day in days"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <select ng-model="data.dayId" ng-value="day.id" ng-options="day.id as (day.date |date:'mm-dd-yy')group by day.name for day in days" required>

</select>
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644402/angular-use-filter-on-ng-options-to-change-the-value-displayed)