# Disable elements in dropdown based on value of (key,value) in map

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, ng-options

```
ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in properties.myMap"
```

I want to create  a dropdown in angular using ng-options. I have a map whose key I use as value and label for the dropdown element.

I want to disable the dropdown elements based on the value of the (key, value) pairs in the map. How do I do this?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644402/angular-use-filter-on-ng-options-to-change-the-value-displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ng-option= "item as item.label disable when  item. disabled for item in items track by item.id

Use angular 1.4