# angular ng-options omit value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have a SELECT dropdown rendering the available options based on a META layer which reflects the data coming back in the service once a selection is made.

One of the potential states is UNKNOWN which is a catchall for any data thats not been allocated a state in the database in the returning results - therefore it is a valid state which is why it appears in the META.

However while it may appear in the returning results if no state or ALL state is selected we don't want to show a state of UNKNOWN in the SELECT options for this form.

Is there a way when I render my SELECT to skip that option/value? The value of UNKNOWN is 0 and here is how I currently render my SELECT...

```
<select name="invoicestatus" id="invoicestatus" class="form-control" ng-model="asCtrl.filterParams.invoiceStatusSelected" ng-options="status as status.Description for status in asCtrl.filterParams.invoiceStatus.DataSource track by status.Value"></select>
```

If it were ng-repeat I could add an ng-if for state.value != 0 to hide it but cant figure out how to omit in my ng-options.

I cannot ask the developer to remove UNKNOWN from the service as it is only in this form that UNKNOWN shouldnt be presented - other systems using that service may require it so has to be handled in the angular for my scenario

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom filter to remove the UNKNOWN option.

A similar question/answer can be found here: [Use filter on ng-options to change the value displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644402/use-filter-on-ng-options-to-change-the-value-displayed)